# NLog Email Target with High Priorty/Importance

Tags: email, nlog

I've recently changed the Email Target log level up one level from Error to Warn.  This is to capture some important user actions which aren't Errors on an application level but user input errors, which I don't class as errors so have logged them as Warn.

So in my subject I've changed

```
subject="NLog Error Message from PoppyService on ${machinename}"
```

to

```
subject="NLog ${level} Message from PoppyService on ${machinename}"
```

so I get a different subject based on the log level, but is there a way to make the email High Importance for Error log level only?  I imagine, I'll have to create a second mail target, one for Error and one for Warn, but I can't find how to change the priority of the email to High.

There isn't a way shown in http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Mail_target.

Comment: But it will be included in the next release

Comment: Excellent I will look out for it.

Comment: It doesn't seem like that functionality ever made it to the next release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no way to do this in the current version of NLog, without creating a custom target.